# Salesforce multi language knowledge & customer community

Tags: community, knowledge, translation

i give you a description of the context.

we are building a community and a knowledge base solution for a customer.

The knowledge base uses two languages (English UK, Italian), where the default language of the knowledge base is English Uk.

Those articles, should be consumed by the users on the community. We expect articles in only English, only Italian, or both.

**Issue-unexpected behaviour**

I created an article only Italian. With a community user, which has as language the italian we expect to be able to see the knowledge article. But, going to the detail page of the article we get "Invalid page".

We are able to see the article only when we create an translation article in Englis (which is the default language of the platform). It seems strange to me, and i don't know if is the behaviour of the platform or, I'm missing any configuration.

anyone had a similar experience, do you have any hint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**USE CASE – Salesforce Case code: 16538643**

**Customer Community – Napili template**

***Requirement:***

The client wants that the their community users should have access on the Knowledge base to all the articles, in all languages. 
In particular, in our project the customer has a Knowledge base in languages (English UK,Italian). Where the default language of KB is English UK.

The User of the Community should see potentially all the articles in the KB independently on the language settings of the user.

***Salesforce standard behaviour - Napili template***

Knowledge Base languages (English UK, Italian), default language English UK. To explain the context and the limits that we found we show 3 use cases.

1) Examples user community with language English UK

The user can see all and only the articles in English UK. 
The user can’t see articles that are only in Italian. If the user try to access them by URL manipulation, the system give invalid page.

2) Example user community with language Italian

The user can see all and only the articles in Italian, independently if the articles has an English UK version (English UK is the default language for the KB platform). 
The Italian user, is not able to see the articles that are only in English UK. If try to reach them by URL manipulation, the system returns invalid page.

3) Example user community with language different from Itanlian or English UK, let say German.

The user can see all and only those articles that has a version in the English UK (the KB default language). If the user try to reach articles that are only in italian through URL manipulation, the system gives invalid page.

***Differences – singular behaviour from our point of view***

The community user with language German, can see KB articles that are not visible by the Italian one.

***Considerations***

The Community user, enabled to the capability to change its own language, can see potentially all the articles in the KB, but he needs to change language in order to see them all.

***Objective of the customer***

The objective is to bypass this filter of the community user language, and allow the user to access to all the KB articles. 
We would give the access to the resources (articles) through the standard service that community use, that mean through the page of Napili dedicated to knowledge “Article detail” page, which give access to the resources through the URL path structure
[Community istance url]+”/”+[community name]+”/s/article/”+[article version id]+”/”+[article url]

Is this Objective reachable through the standard “Article detail” behaviour of the Napili/community capabilities?

***Summary***

In our project, we are getting stuck on the scenarios where the standard community, is giving invalid page.

***Salesforce Feedback***

Salesforce said that this is the standard behaviour, and the community is designed to show to the users all the articles of the language used by the community user, and if the user language of the community language is not configured in the Knowledge base, than the user will  see the articles of the standard language of Knowledge Base. 
If you want to realize the request of the customer, is required to find a workaround.

***Our actions after the feedback***

We are prociding to avoid to use the community page “article”, and we are going to use a customer object that will allow us to wrap Knowledge Base to the community using the page “detail”.

I hope this will help others that may have a similar limitation.

Comment: Insane that this is how an enterprise application was "designed"

Comment: OrchestraCMS handles multi lingual the way you would expect